# What is the proper way to capture a "Response too large to return error" in Google BigQuery API for PHP?

Tags: php, google-bigquery

In the Google BigQuery web interface, if I run a query that returns a response that is too large, I receive the message:

Error: Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration.

How can I capture this error message in the Google BigQuery API interface when running a query that does not have allowLargeResults set in the job configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: Here's a summary of what resolved it for me.  In summary, I couldn't get it to throw an error for Synchronous Queries, but was able to get it to throw for Asynchronous Queries.

Here is a sample query with a response too large to return:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline] LIMIT 1000000;"
```

### Synchronous Queries

Running a synchronous query with jobs.query:

```
try {
  $query_request = new Google_Service_Bigquery_QueryRequest();
  $query_request->setQuery($query);
  $res = $this->gbq_service->jobs->query($this->_project_id, $query_request);
  return $res;
} catch (Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage());
}
```

The response I receive is:

```
{
  "cacheHit": null,
  "jobComplete": false,
  "kind": "bigquery#queryResponse",
  "pageToken": null,
  "totalBytesProcessed": null,
  "totalRows": null
}
```

So in this case, I still don't receive the desired "response too large to return".

### Asynchronous Queries

If I run the job as an asynchronous query, the job status is eventually set to DONE, and on checking the results, an error is thrown with message:

```
{
  "error": "Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/.../queries/job_2VICoK6yX0YMM_zRkJ10hT9mom8?timeoutMs=1000000&maxResults=100: (403) Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors",
}
```

Telling me that I need to save the results as a table and set allowLargeResults to true.

So, the short answer is- run your queries as asynchronous queries.

### Update

I've contacted google and they mentioned it may be a bug in the php api.  They have said they will forward it to the php gbq API people.

Comment: @rmg You should edit your original question and update that with new question. This is not a forum. And what you posted here is type ANSWER so will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I answered my own question because the other two answers did not actually solve the problem, though they did help me figure out what was going on.  Of the three answers, this one should be the best answer for a user with a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

We use this fragment to handle errors, and it helped out:

We have also when we place the job, and later when we check the status of the job in a loop, as that error popups up when the job is done.

```
try {
                try {
                    $job = $bq->jobs->insert(PROJECT_ID, $job);
                } catch (Google_IO_Exception $e) {
                    $this->e('Exception: ' . $e->getMessage(), 'red');
                    $this->e('Strace: ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
                    if ($e->getMessage() == 'SSL connect error') {
                        $this->clearTokenFile();
                        $this->releaseJob();
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                $status = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobStatus();
                $status = $job->getStatus();

                if (0 != $status->count()) {
                    $err_res = $status->getErrorResult();
                    $this->e($err_res->getMessage(), 'red');

                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
                $this->e('Exception: ' . $e->getMessage(), 'red');
                return false;
            }
```

on and insertAll we have, here pay attention to the `reason` field:

```
try {
            $resp = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllResponse();
            $resp = $bq->tabledata->insertAll($project_id, $dataset_id, static::tableId(), $request);
            $errors = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllResponseInsertErrors();
            $errors = @$resp->getInsertErrors();
            if (!empty($errors)) {
                $error_msg = "\r\nRequest Headers: \r\n" . json_encode($client->request->getRequestHeaders()) . "\r\nResponse Headers: \r\n" . json_encode($client->request->getResponseHeaders()) . "\r\nRequest Body:\r\n" . $client->request->getPostBody() . "\r\nResponse Body:\r\n" . $client->request->getResponseBody() . "\r\n";
                if (is_array($errors)) {
                    foreach ($errors as $eP) {
                        $arr = $eP->getErrors();
                        $line = $eP->getIndex();
                        if (is_array($arr)) {
                            foreach ($arr as $e) {
                                switch ($e->getReason()) {
                                    case "stopped":
                                        break;
                                    case "timeout":
                                        $failed_lines[] = $line;
                                        $last_reason = $e->getReason();
                                        $error_msg.= sprintf("Timeout on line %s, reason: %s, msg: %s\r\n", $line, $e->getReason(), $e->getMessage());
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        $error_msg.= sprintf("Error on line %s, reason: %s, msg: %s\r\n", $line, $e->getReason(), $e->getMessage());
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            $error_msg.= json_encode($arr) . "\r\n";
                        }
                    }
                    $this->setErrorMessage($error_msg);
                } else {
                    $this->setErrorMessage($errors);
                }
                //print_r($errors);
                //exit;
                $success = false;
            }
            return $ret;
        } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
            $this->setErrors($e->getErrors())->setErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            throw $e;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In respective BigQuery API - [Jobs: get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get) this info is in [status.errorResult](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#resource) 
Respectivelly in
`reason` property:  *responseTooLarge*
`message` property:  *Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration. For more details, ...*

You can also check status.errors for more details for all errors encountered during job execution